# Using an image that has effects on the background as a header for a website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use an image as a header for a website. The thing is that it has a glow on the background of it so when i put it on the website then it looks out of place despite the whole background of the website having a similar color. Is there any solution to this?

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sqbkcg6r/5/

```
<header>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Izahu1c.png">
</header




body{
    background-color:#e7d2c9;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The question is not really clear.

Comment: I am trying to make that image as a header and blend in with the background color of the webpage. They have similar colors but as you can see in that jsfiddle that it does not blend in.

Comment: Well, you have to change something, for example the image or the background... Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/sqbkcg6r/6/ (I still don't know *how you want it to look*)

Comment: Yea that is close but on the bottom/top you can notice it's still distinguished from the whole color of the page. On the left and right it looks right and blends it right. I think it's because the glow is too much on the bottom,maybe i need to shorten it in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you could try using a gradient as a background to match it up, it might take some time to get it just right..I use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ for quick gradients. Or you could try to mess around with opacity using rgba.. Still not sure what it is you are going for exactly.

```
<header>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Izahu1c.png">
</header>


body {
    background-color: rgba(231, 210, 201, .5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a transparent picture and all the rest handled by CSS ?

File will looks something like this:
[image]
and **CSS** like so :

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(232, 213, 205, 1) 0%, rgba(247, 241, 239, 0.69) 50%, rgba(232, 213, 205, 1) 100%);
}
header {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw3qW.png") no-repeat top center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    min-height: 90px;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqbkcg6r/12/)

Ps: if you own fonts, best is even using it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

Answer (score 0):

OK, you need to try a different path:

1) modify your image making it bigger so you make sure the glow fits **COMPLETELY** in the image
2) get rid of your header image and add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    background:#e7d2c9 url('http://i.imgur.com/Izahu1c.png') no-repeat top center;
}
```

where the image is your image, of course

**ALTERNATIVE**

1) again, do the same about the glow, only that keep the logo in a different image. Thus, you'll have image_bg.png and image_logo.png. This time don't get rid of the header image
2) repeat the same CSS as above, and add this line:

```
header{text-align:center}
header img{margin:30px auto 0 /* 30 and 0 should be changed to whatever you want, just keep auto */}
```

A final alternative would be to use a radial gradient instead of that glow. For this, you can use [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), and your code would be like this:

```
body{background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%, #e7d2c9 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e7d2c9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e7d2c9 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e7d2c9 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e7d2c9 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #ffffff 0%,#e7d2c9 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e7d2c9',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */}
```

but I prefer to use images, it works 10x better than gradients across browsers. Also, you'll need additional markup for IE9. Anyways, test and see which option fits you better